# My Favicon is not showing up in Brave (HTML)

Tags: html, favicon, brave

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Digvijay Singh</title>
    <link rel="favicon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
```

I tried adding favicons present on my folder but it is not showing up.

Comment: Does it show up in Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge?

Comment: Is your favicon placed at `website/favicon.ico`? Have you cleared your cache? Have you tested it with other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing Browser cache and do check that the icon is less than 100kb(as it may be the cause that the icon isn't loading). You can check Security settings or disable any extensions that might be blocking it to load.